Does a mirror still exist for CentOS-3.9-srcDVD.iso?
I am looking for a copy of the RPM source code DVD for CentOS 3.9. The file name is "CentOS-3.9-srcDVD.iso". There are lots of mirrors for the CDs but I have been unable to locate the DVD.

Out of pure curiosity: why? I mean ... Centos 3 went EOL 2010.

@tink I would only have to burn a single DVD instead of three CDs (or DVDs) with the CD-size ISOs.

The question is not so much about the medium. Why an OS that's been obsolete for 14 years?

This is the latest version of CentOS that will boot on my Pentium 233 MMX. I also tried 4.9 and 5.11, but both of those cause the system to hard reset while booting the install disc or a drive where CentOS has already been installed. To answer to your question, I am experimenting with old versions of Linux on vintage hardware.

I remember that generation of PCs, and good on you to upgrade your PC with a DVD drive instead of sticking with the era-appropriate 4× speed CD-ROM drive!

but are you sure you need the srcDVD image, not the binDVD image?

I have a vague vague memory that way back then only the CDs were available for direct download and the DVDs had to be torrented.

So, maybe a better question is "How to merge the CD downloads into a DVD?"?

@MarcusMüller Unless the disc contains Red Book audio, I always prefer a DVD for the higher transfer rate, especially for installers. The drive in this system couldn't read burned discs anyways, so it needed to be replaced.

Here is the official link:
https://vault.centos.org/3.9/isos/SRPMS/
Google still works :-) You'll need a torrent client to download it:


your link doesn't contain the file that was asked for.

It does, CentOS-3.9-srcDVD.torrent. In the end the DVD is irrelevant cause the three CD ISO images feature the same content.

@MarcusMüller Why you down vote the 2 answer?

a torrent link is useless; it doesn't point to the file, but a description of the file; there's nobody seeding that torrent, so this isn't a source for the file asked for.

"In the end the DVD is irrelevant cause the three CD ISO images feature the same content." Thanks for downvotes Marcus. Also I'm not responsible for the fact that currently no one is seeding it. A torrent link is no different than a URL. You were not going to post the entire file either.

@ArtemS.Tashkinov sorry for… uh… pointing out that something that isn't going to help OP isn't going to help OP? Linking to a torrent with no seeders is exactly as helpful as giving a link to a server that is offline: it's not your fault that there's no seeders, but it's also not helpful of you. And arguing that I can't post a link either so I shouldn't downvote makes no sense; hover over the downvote triangle: it notably says "this answer is not useful", not "I have to have a better answer before clicking on this button". Zhro explicitly said they don't want the CDs.
